# When is a Float not a float?

Tags: delphi, type-conversion, docto

A user of my utility ([docto](https://github.com/tobya/DocTo/)) has logged an issue on github that he is getting an error.  The error is

> Error: EConvertError '11.0' is not a valid floating point value

Now on the face of it '11.0' looks to me like a valid floating point number, indeed the code that I assume is causing the error is [here](https://github.com/tobya/DocTo/blob/master/src/WordUtils.pas#L113)

```
if (strtofloat(OfficeAppVersion) < 14) then
```

I can't reproduce the error even though I have version '14.0' of word installed.

Is there any reason why '11.0' would not be being recognised as a float by Delphi's `strtofloat` function.

My initial idea was to put a trim in to see if there are any hidden characters

```
if (strtofloat(trim(OfficeAppVersion)) < 14) then
```

Any ideas gratefully recieved.

Comment: The decimal point might be something else than `'.'` in the target locale.

Comment: Brilliant thank you.  First one to put it as an answer gets accepted.

Comment: A float not a float when decimal point not a point :) but a comma in locale settings for example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As others have stated, the problem is that the machine's default locale uses a different character than `'.'` for the decimal separator.  If you need to convert a string that uses `'.'`, you can use the overloaded version of `StrToFloat()` that accepts a `TFormatSettings` as input:

```
var
  fmt: TFormatSettings;
begin
  fmt := TFormatSettings.Create; // get default settings first
  fmt.DecimalSeparator := '.'; // customize as needed
  if (StrToFloat(OfficeAppVersion, fmt) < 14) then
  ...
end;
```

Answer (score 2):

Most probably your users locale uses comma as decimalseparator